# mysql function syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

```
function DisplayPoints()
{

mysql_select_db('$database');
$qry = "Select points from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwd' and confirmcode='y'";
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
        $points = $rows['points'];
    echo " $points";

}
```

My idea was to make kind of points system in website. When user logins into page then in main page header you can see how much points you have.

Comment: Just FYI: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. Please consider to use a different database API.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text, you need to apply a hashing function to them, like with SHA1()

Comment: @Pinqniq yes this code has multiple problems, but don't discredit fixing any of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array needs a result resource and not an SQL query.
See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

first get the result:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

and then fetch the array

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

As Dennis pointed out, you shouldnt be using mysql_* anymore. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.